# Adding HtmlHelper to translate field name into column header using resource file

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, lambda

I am trying to extend the `HtmlHelper` so it can translate field names from the Linq entities using a simple resource file.
The problem is that i can't get the extended method signature right. Here the code:

```
public static class HtmlHelperExtension
{
    public static MvcHtmlString HeaderFromResource<TModel,
         TValue>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> html, Expression<Func<TModel, TValue>> expression)
    {
       ...
       return  (MvcHtmlString)html.Raw(something)
    }
}
```

When i try to use it inside the view, like this:

```
@model IEnumerable<WebApp.Models.TransferInConfig>
...
<th>
       @Html.HeaderFromResource(model => model.RemotePath) 
</th>
```

i get the following error:

> 'IEnumerable' does not contain a definition for
>   'RemotePath' and no extension method 'RemotePath'

Comment: Edit you question please. Your sample code has `HeaderFromResource` and usage showing `@Html.LabelForFromResouce(model => model.IncludeMask)` and error message is for `RemotePath`. Nothing is linked.

Comment: Also add the definition of your Extension method.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public static MvcHtmlString HeaderFromResource<TModel, TValue>( this HtmlHelper<IEnumerable<TModel>> html,   Expression<Func<TModel, TValue>> expression)
{
    var headerName = expression.Body.ToString() //return model.Connection.RemotePath
        .Split('.')
        .Last(); 

    if (Properties.Resources.ResourceManager.GetString(headerName) != null)
        headerName = Properties.Resources.ResourceManager.GetString(headerName);

    return MvcHtmlString.Create(headerName);
```

The only thing i needed to do was to look up on the manual for the signature of `DisplayForName`, but i am not use it anymore. Should be a better way to get the name of the field from the expression, anyway this one works for me.

Answer (score 1):

Well to start your model is an IEnumerable, it indeed does not have RemotePath definition, but the items in it does (probably). So you will have to loop through your model list first and use each items. Something like this

```
foreach (var item in model){
   @Html.HeaderFromResource(item => item.RemotePath)  
}
```

Comment: True, yet the HtmlHelper.DisplayForName method accepts the IEnumerable. My problem is precisely how to define the signature right, i only know that it is an expression, but have some constrains that i don't am aware of or don't now how to properly codify them.  This solution probably will work but loses the capacity to suppress columns, change order, etc... The goal is only to be able to translate one at a time.

Comment: If you implement it right away maybe. But you could add metadata. Like order and visibility: hidden or visible status in your model to reflect you data. That will enable the ordering and showing column you are mentioning.

Comment: Sorry, but that just adds to the problem.